# What are alternative or equivalent definitions of a positive-definite function on a group?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-product

The standard definition of a positive-definite function on a group goes as follows:

Let $\varphi : G \rightarrow L(H)$, where $G$ is a group (with an involution) and $H$ a Hilbert space. $L(H)$ is the space of all linear operators.

We say, that $\varphi$ is positive-definite, if:

$$\forall_{f : G \rightarrow H} \quad \sum_{s,t \in G} \langle \varphi(s^* t) f(t), f(s) \rangle \ge 0$$ where $f$ has finite support.

---

I know, that you can find alternative and equivalent definitions for the boundedness condition (as Szafraniec showed).

But I am yet to find alternative or equivalent definitions of positive definiteness itself.

Does anyone know some alternative or equivalent ways to define positive definiteness?

Comment: All positive definite functions on $G$ extend to a completely positive map from the full group $C^\ast$-algebra $C^\ast(G)$, so you can say $\varphi$ is positive definite iff it is the restriction of a cp map $C^\ast(G) \to L(H)$. Not sure if that’s really helpful though.

Comment: If you are willing to restrict yourself to locally compact abelian groups, Bochner's theorem provides a characterisation of continuous positive-definite functions, see [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134419/intuitions-about-positive-definite-functions) on MSE for further details.

Comment: For non-abelian groups, there are complete descriptions of characters on lattices in higher-rank semisimple Lie groups (due to B.Bekka and J.Peterson, for example). You might be interested in [dilation theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naimark%27s_dilation_theorem), which are used to study positive-definite functions on non-abelian groups, see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123607000493), for example.

Comment: @PeterKosenko The specific group I am working with is the algebra of continuous functions on the boundary of $X$, while $\varphi$ is defined for all $s \in S = C(\partial X)$ here as $\varphi(s) := s(T)$ for $T$ being a contraction in $H$ (here, $T$ is fixed for all $s$!). The question I have, more specifically, is how I can show that $\varphi$ is positive definite under these circumstances. That's why I was/am looking for alternative definitions, as I can't find a way to directly show it using the "original" definition of positive definiteness.

Comment: @S-F If you just have $T$ being a contraction without assuming normality and $s$ is just continuous, how do you even define $s(T)$?

Comment: @DavidGao I simply define it by inserting $T$ as the variable in the function $s$. Example: $s(x) = x^2 + x$, then $s(T) = T^2 + T$.

Comment: @S-F This works if $s$ is a polynomial, or more generally analytic. It doesn’t make sense if $s$ is just continuous.

Comment: @DavidGao Why? To be honest, originally, I actually used the group of rational functions $R(X)$, but because I needed it to be an algebra with an involution (just like in the definition of positive definiteness), I needed to extend it to the whole class of continuous functions.

Comment: S-F: You ask @DavidGao "why?" but I would turn the question round: why do you think that you can define $f(T)$ if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function? For instance, suppose $\partial X$ is the unit circle, and I choose $f$ to be some nasty non-differentiable sawtooth function. Moreover, functional calculus usually only works for functions that are defined on the spectrum of the original operator.

Comment: I am also not sure what you are hoping for when you seek "an alternative/equivalent definition of positive-definiteness". The definition is what it is. Why do you think it should be equivalent to something that looks different?

Comment: @S-F Maybe a specific example: if $s(z) = |z|^2$, what is $s(T)$? Is it $T^\ast T$ or $TT^\ast$ or something else? (Note that $T^\ast T$ and $TT^\ast$ are already different if $T$ is not normal.)

Comment: @S-F Also, I should point out this terminology issue: $C(\partial X)$ and $R(X)$ are *algebras*, not *groups*. Those are two completely different things.

Comment: @S-F Regardless, in your specific example you could look at Theorem 2.6 in “Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras” by Vern Paulsen. It’s not positivity on a $\ast$-algebra - again that doesn’t make sense with just a contraction $T$, but it is positivity on an operator system - on which you can still talk about positive elements and maps.

Comment: Cross Posted on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849468/what-are-alternative-or-equivalent-definitions-of-a-positive-definite-function-o

Comment: @PeterKosenko Could you give a reference for the characterization of characters on lattices in higher-rank semisimple Lie groups?

Comment: I have voted to close because the comments seem to indicate that the OP is basing the question on a misunderstanding about positive maps between operator systems

Comment: @DavidGao This sounds interesting, thanks.

Comment: Also, a technical point: unless one imposes extra assumptions, $R_0(X)$, the algebra of rational functions with poles outside $X$, is not dense in $C(\partial X)$. In fact you can have compact subsets $X\subset{\mathbb C}$ which have empty interior and satisfy $R_0(X)$ not dense in $C(X)$ (examples can be provided by so-called "Swiss cheeses")

Comment: @YemonChoi I don't know where exactly I misunderstood something. The definition I gave for positive-definite maps is true?

Comment: @YemonChoi The theorem I use to argue that one can extend a representation $R(X) \rightarrow L(H)$ to a representation $C(\partial X) \rightarrow L(H)$ is Theorem 4.2 in "Decompositions of non-contractive operator-valued representations of Banach algebras" by Szafraniec.

Comment: Your definition is true, but you seem to be asking about positive-definiteness for linear maps between $*$-algebras, which is a much more special case. Also your question is broad and ill-defined; if you have a specific question about showing that a certain linear map is positive in the sense of Paulsen's book, then maybe you should ask that question directly.

Comment: The theorem of Szafraniec that you refer to has extra conditions on the representation. It is absolutely not true that an arbitrary bounded homomorphism $R(X) \to L(H)$ extends to a bounded homomorphism $C(\partial X) \to L(H)$, this fails even for the disc algebra and the natural representation of the disc algebra by multiplication operators on Hardy space >

Comment: >  In this representation, the generator $Z$ of the disc algebra is mapped to a **non-invertible** isometry; but when considered as an element of $C({\mathbb T})$, $Z$ is invertible, so any bounded unital HM $C({\mathbb T})\to L(H)$ would map $Z$ to an invertible operator.

Comment: @YemonChoi But why is this theorem then used in the proof of Theorem 1 in "Representation generated by a finite number of Hilbert space operators" by Marek Kosiek (you can find it in the middle of page 313, starting with "Hence by [7], Theorem 4.2, ...")? There were no additional restrictions of non-invertibility?

Comment: @MaoWao I meant these papers: [Operator-algebraic superridigity for $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}), n \ge 3$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-007-0050-5) and [Character rigidity for lattices in higher-rank groups](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/peters10/rigidity.pdf).

Comment: @S-F Yemon was assuming you’re actually talking about the disc algebra, so $X = \mathbb{D}$ and $\partial X = \mathbb{T}$. In the paper of Kosiek there’re *lots* of restrictions on what Theorem 4.2 of [7] is being applied to, with restrictions to $S_i$ (so $T_i$ Are restricted to $H_i$), and all these representations have systems of elementary measures orthogonal singular to $R^\perp_{j_1, \cdots, j_m}$ and all that. This should *exactly tell* you that, if $K = \mathbb{D}$, all these conditions would exactly force $T$, restricted to $H_i$, to be an invertible normal operator.

Comment: @S-F In fact, that’s even a part of what the paper used the theorem to conclude. The paper concludes that the operators, restricted to $H_i$, have common spectral measures on $\partial X$. That in particular tells you that the spectra of these operators, restricted to $H_i$, are within $\partial X$ - which, if $\partial X = \mathbb{T}$, would already tell you the operators in question are invertible.

Comment: @S-F *Please*, for the sake of saving your own time and everyone else’s time in the future, read the papers *thoroughly* and think through the implications *before* asking questions. And if you have to ask questions, *please* just directly cite the paper you’re confused about instead of asking these general and vague questions, only for people to realize your question comes from a misreading of whatever paper you’re reading and/or a misunderstanding of relevant concepts.